# Python-Tkinter-Windows 7 How do I tie windows together

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

How do I tie a parent and child window together with Python-Tkinter under Windows 7 so that if I change the focus to another application, I can restore focus to the parent and child.

Code example for creating child and parent windows:

```
def wait_window(root):
   wait_window = Toplevel(root)
   wait_window.minsize(300,100)
   wait_message = "Something clever \n"
   Label(wait_window,text=wait_message).grid(row=0,column=0)
   wait_window.config(cursor="wait")
   wait_window.update()
   root.update()

#########
root = Tk()
root.minsize(600,300)
root.geometry("600x400")
root.wm_title("Some title")
wait_window(root)
root.mainloop
```

If I move the Windows focus to another application, the two windows are now disconnected and I cannot bring both back into focus.

Comment: only one window of any type (tkinter or not) can have focus. What do you mean by "bring both back into focus"? Do you just want to bring them back so that they both are visible? Have you tried using [wm_group](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.group-method)?

Comment: I was not aware of wm_group, THANK YOU!!.  Could you provide a short example??